# Using WAMP, trying to create a plugin, getting error: You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

Tags: plugin-development

Just trying to create a simple plugin with some Theme Options so I can practice.  When I try to access the Theme Options page under Settings... I get the: You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

This is all I have in the plugin:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function(){
    add_options_page( 'Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'administrator', __FILE__, function(){
        echo 'Hello';
    });
});
```

Here are the parameters from the WordPress codex:

```
<?php
add_options_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
?>
```

I am the admin.  Tried creating another admin account, same result.  Tried setting the slug parameter to a different slug, same result.  I'm using WAMP on my local machine.

Any ideas? I came up short when trying to search for this issue when using WAMP on a local machine.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

`administrator` isn't a capability, it is a [role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Roles), so the reason you get that error is because WordPress doesn't recognizes the capability you gave.

If you look up the [capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Administrator) of the administrator role, you can see that the administrator is the only one with the capability `manage_options`. This is the one you should use.

So what you can do is change the capability to `manage_options`:

```
add_options_page( __( 'Theme Options' ), __( 'Theme Options' ), 'manage_options', __FILE__, function() {
    echo 'Hello';
} );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: manage_options also didn't work.  I believe it has something to do with setting __FILE__ as the slug.  When I change it to js_options.php ... it works.  I'm still curious as to why __FILE__ wouldn't work though?

Comment: I think because the menu-slug has to be unique, when you use `__FILE__`, it never will be an unique filename, because it already exists.